Associated address does not match seed derivation
I have tried to transfer spl token from user account to program(contract) I wrote this contract with help of GPT have fixed many things now I stuck here with this error
solpg ERROR
Running client...
  client.ts:

    User ATA account: 3XNcYXdfZ5k1C6bFw3JeZD6zeChbbiyfKXkbs75tKo3G
    Vault PDA account: D3kGGFN28uqBrfyYPpAy2etZ9Jv1UjWuuEWKNJDWNZGB
$ 
    Error in main execution: { [Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address]
  logs: 
   [ 'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
     'Program log: Create',
     'Program log: Error: Associated address does not match seed derivation',
     'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 8057 of 200000 compute units',
     'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address' ] }

$ 

lib.rs
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;
use anchor_spl::token::{
    self, transfer_checked, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, TransferChecked as SPLTransferChecked,
};

declare_id!("7KNzQPbmGAN4G45ncYvmCbh3xpdaYzh2iyRbZRtUwkUV");

#[program]
pub mod deposit_and_release {
    use super::*;

    pub fn deposit(ctx: Context<Deposit>, amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        msg!("Deposit function called with amount: {}", amount);

        // Validate deposit amount
        if amount < 1_000_000 || amount > 10_000_000 {
            msg!("Invalid deposit amount: {}", amount);
            return Err(ProgramError::Custom(ErrorCode::InvalidDepositAmount as u32));
        }

        // Set up the CPI (cross-program invocation) context for the token transfer
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = SPLTransferChecked {
            from: ctx.accounts.depositor.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.depositor.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        // Execute the token transfer
        transfer_checked(cpi_ctx, amount, ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.decimals)?;

        msg!(
            "Successfully transferred {} tokens from user's ATA to program's PDA vault.",
            amount
        );
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Deposit<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub depositor: Signer<'info>, // User wallet that authorizes the transfer
    #[account(mut, constraint = user_deposit.owner == depositor.key())]
    pub user_deposit: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, // User's associated token account (ATA)
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"vault", usdc_mint.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    // Ensure PDA ownership by program
    pub vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, // PDA vault for receiving tokens
    pub usdc_mint: Account<'info, Mint>, // Token mint for USDC
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>, // Token program for the transfer
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, // System program
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Invalid deposit amount.")]
    InvalidDepositAmount,
}

client.ts
import anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import {
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  getAssociatedTokenAddress,
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

const solpg = pg;
const connection = solpg.connection;
const program = solpg.program;

async function main() {
  const usdcMintAddress = new PublicKey(
    "88vRvJtjbESDcQw8yDwGgu1HAotP6LPikpfp1UjsPy2K"
  );

  const wallet = solpg.wallet;
  const userPublicKey = wallet.publicKey;

  // Create user token account associated with USDC mint
  const userTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    usdcMintAddress,
    userPublicKey,
    false,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  console.log("User ATA account:", userTokenAccount.toString());

  // Derive the PDA for the program-owned vault account
  const [vaultAccount, vaultBump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [Buffer.from("vault"), usdcMintAddress.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  console.log("Vault PDA account:", vaultAccount.toString());

  // Check if the vault account exists, if not, create it
  const vaultAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(vaultAccount);
  if (!vaultAccountInfo) {
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey, // Payer
        vaultAccount, // ATA address
        program.programId, // Owner of the ATA (program PDA)
        usdcMintAddress, // Mint address
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    // Send transaction to create the ATA
    await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [wallet.keypair]);
    console.log("Vault ATA account created.");
  }

  // Define deposit amount (1 USDC with 6 decimals)
  const depositAmount = 1_000_000;

  // Call the deposit function from the program
  try {
    await program.rpc.deposit(new anchor.BN(depositAmount), {
      accounts: {
        depositor: userPublicKey,
        userDeposit: userTokenAccount,
        vault: vaultAccount,
        usdcMint: usdcMintAddress,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [],
    });

    console.log("Deposited 1 USDC into the vault!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Transaction failed:", error);
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error in main execution:", err);
});

My ultimate goal is to transfer money to contract then later from contract I should transfer it to some other wallets any help or any example?
